# Laravel DependencyInjection is this "okay" to do?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

To handle some logic of my application I created a Service in `App/Services/CarsService.php`.

I injected this service in my controller through DependencyInjection like so:

CarsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Services\CarsService;

class CarsController extends Controller
{
    /** @var  CarsService $carsService */
    private $carsService;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @param CarsService $carsService
     */
    public function __construct(CarsService $carsService)
    {
        $this->carsService = $carsService;
    }
```

So for example when I want to query all the cars with some parameters provided by the user I do something like this in one of my controller methods:

```
$cars = $this->carsService->getCars($brand, $type);
```

This keeps my controller clean and my logic is seperated in a Service, seems pretty good and clean to me.

But my question is actually if this is bad practice to do in Laravel? I imagine that there might be a more "Laravel-y" way to handle this.

Comment: If dependency injection is considered as a bad practice within a framework, you shouldn't use that framework.
As you mentionned this help keep your code clean and also allow you to create composable classes and services. This is a best practice, whatever the framework, whatever the langage.

Comment: @Unex I am fairly new to Laravel so I am not sure if it's considered as bad practice, I want to know if what I am doing is the "best/most clean" way to do it. Laravel has a big community and is one of the biggest frameworks so I think there might be a better way to handle this with the philosophy of the Laravel framework.

Comment: I don't use laravel so I couldn't say if there is something dedicated to dependency injection within the framework. Although, from an OOP point of view, this is how dependency injection should be handled. It's clean, it's easy to read and composable. What else would you want ? :D

Comment: Well there is something called `ServiceProviders` within Laravel and I might think that is a better way to handle DI but I am not sure. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/providers

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use a service for that. Inject and use model if you're using Eloquent. Or use repository if you're using Query Builder, raw queries or API. For example:

```
public function __construct(Car $car)
{
    $this->car = $car;
}

$this->car->getByBrandAndType($brand, $type);
```

If you're asking about [is using IoC container a good or a bad practice](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#use-ioc-container-or-facades-instead-of-new-class), it's definitely a good tool to use in any app.

Comment: Well, a repository is a specific service pattern so i don't see where the issue is. I think the question is more about how to handle dependency injection in Laravel than wheter he needed a service or a model.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your response, I do more complex logic in my service the getCars() is just a simple example.

Comment: Exactly as @Unex says, the question is more about how to handle dependency injection in Laravel.

Comment: @user3652775 if there is some business logic, then sure, use service.